# Breakpoint breaking at wrong line

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

[image: breakpoint wrong line]

The screen shot should be pretty self-explanatory, but I am having issues ensuring my `viewDidAppear` method is being called.  When I set a breakpoint, it breaks in `viewDidLoad`.

As a side note, none of my `NSLog()`s are writing to the console either.

I did clean my build directory as I had seen recommended elsewhere, but no joy.

Comment: Solution is posted as an answer below.  Must wait 2 days before I can select it as best answer.

Comment: Didn'nt you tried for clean the build targer?

Comment: I sure did, nothing I did in XCode fixed the problem.  Solution was cleaning the Simulator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution was (as originally suspected... bad cached data.  But looking in the wrong place.  Someone in the iOS Simulator, the app was not being updated and was running off old data.

Deleted app from Simulator (Reset Contents and Settings) and all is good with the world.

Killing the derived data both manually in Finder and through Xcode did not give a complete solution.

Appreciate you all that were quick to respond.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a two reasons...

1.Your program is crashing in that line itself before the breakpoint.

2.After compiling you have deleted 6 lines, therefore the breakpoint shows 6 lines later.

**Never put enter or remove empty lines, while you put breakpoints in your code. You will not get breakpoint at  correct line.**

Comment: AKV, if this were the case, would a simple re-build or clean fix the issue?

Comment: Even a simple save and recompile and build will. Did you try?

Comment: AKV, yes.  As mentioned in the question, cleaned the build directory.  Have ensured the project is saved, re-built, cleaned, restarted XCode

Comment: then your program is crashing.... try to mark a breakpoint (BP) in viewDidLoad and step into and check.

Comment: Not crashing, I bypass the breakpoint and everything works fine.  I think the 6 lines is the issue (as I added 6 lines of `viewDidAppear` code).  Fixing it is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

try to add breakpoint at the line [super viewDidLoad];
and then to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

press **command+alt+b** to see all breakpoints.

select the breakpoint that you want to remove and press delete.

if problem is not solve then do follwing

With-in "Build Settings" under the project target change the "Optimization Level" for "Debug" to "None".

**OR**

**In xCode4:**

Your Project Name -> Edit Scheme
Info tab (in run configuration)
Set Build Configuration to "Debug", Debugger - to "LLDB" ("GDB" was before)
Run your project..

Comment: @JasonPawlak- is it break point or error ??? in your situation, u can perform step over ???